# decrypt a cipher -- RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, sha

In my Rails App, I have a client 'C1' who will send me the username of C1's clients. I and C1 share a salt. C1 will send me the username encrypted with the help of the shared salt. Now I need to decrypt it and get the original username and store it in my dB. How can I do it?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What encryption algorithm are you using? The tags seem to indicate you are using SHA1 which is hashing algorithm and thus cannot be reversed ("decrypted")

Comment: using Digest::SHA1.hexdigest method

Comment: @Pierre so is there any other way around?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused about cryptography in general.

The SHA's are [Cryptographic Hash Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). They are designed so as not to be reversible.

If you want secure communication between yourself and the client use a channel with end-to-end encryption, such as [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) (or any other [hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)), the solution is to generate the same hash on the server side and compare it with what was sent. If the resulting hash on the server side is the same as hash sent by the client it's likely the correct username.

In ruby Digest::SHA1.hexdigest would allow you to generate a SHA1 hash.

Comment: But @Pierre, as I have mentioned in my question my client has its own users which I don't know of. My client sends me an encrypted username which I need to decrypt and save in my dB. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: SHA1 cannot be reversed. You'll need to use another algorithm. You could use AES with a shared key or a public/private key system (PKI)

Comment: @Rohit: The idea is that you need to store the hashed version on the server side, and then when an authentication occurs you hash the username and check it against the database. This might seem more inconvenient but in reality it allows you a lot more security. If the database is cracked, the usernames are safe unless the salt is also discovered.

Comment: @Rohit Are you sure you're using SHA1? If you're using the hashing for confidentiality, using an SSL tunnel from C1 to your system would also be a way around it. Can you give more details to what you are trying to do?